# Hidden field value assigned during on submit jquery is empty during postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm assigning a value to hiddenfield during the submit jquery event of a button. I can see the value is set for hiddenfield but when I try to access the hiddenfield value in postback on server side,it is empty. I can access the value of the text field on the same form during post back

My aspx looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/" id="mainform">

<input type="text" id="test" name="test" class="test-name"> //this has to be an html element

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenfield" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" >   //this has to be an html element
```

My Javascript looks like this

```
$('.js-card-entry-submit').submit.on('click', function (e) {

//do something

$("#hiddenfield").attr("value", myvalue);//assign value to hiddenfield
}
```

.Net Webforms:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack)
        {
            var value = hiddenfield.Value; // this is empty
            var name = Request.Form["test-name"]; // I can access the value of this text field
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-card-entry-submit').submit.on('click', function (e) {
    //do something
    $(hiddenfield).attr("value", value);// Replace this line with
    $('#hiddenfield').val("your value");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the value from hiddenfield . I'm trying to assign value to hiddenfield through jquery and access during postback. I've updated my question as well if it's not clear

Comment: See, code behind process you are doing right to fetch the hidden field data but you are doing wrong at the time of set data into hidden field into client side on jquery. process to set the data into jquery is:    $('#hiddenfield').val("your value");

Answer (score 0):

since you are assigning value why not use pure `html` code instead of `asp` like

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield"/>
```

your script will be like this

```
 $("#hiddenfield").val("123");
 $(this).submit(); //this will submit the form
```

and in `postback`

```
if (IsPostBack)
   {
       String value = Request.Form["hiddenfield"];
   }
```